# Is there a quick way to grab a the ending of current page url? Django

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I have a page. `www.example.com/chat/testuser`

I want to grab the username (testuser). I'm doing this within the template in order to pass along in an ajax call.
Is there a simple way? Something like {{ request.path }} (this returns full path).

Comment: You should be able to get `testuser` with  `request.get_full_path.rsplit('/', 1)[1]` or `{% set usernames = request.get_full_path.split('/') %}
{% for username in usernames %}
<p>{{ username }}</p>
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

`{{ request.user }}` might do the trick.

**Edit:**

Here's are some solutions using `request.path`. Assuming it returns the string "/chat/testuser", you can use one of these filters:

```
{{ request.path|cut:"/chat/" }}

{{ request.path|slice:"6:" }}
```

to remove the unwanted portion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21152659)

Comment: Got it. Appended a hopefully better answer.